# How do I total several columns up to a certain point?

Tags: r, gps, accelerometer

So I have a dataframe which combines accelerometer and GPS data for a Tawny Owl individual. I've used the 'move' package to calculate the distance travelled and speed between consecutive GPS coordinates, but I've ran into a problem when I try to analyse this data.

[image]

The problem is that the accelerometer data is averaged over every second, while the GPS data is much more erratic and often has gaps of many seconds, or even minutes, between readings.

Basically what I want to know is; is there a way for me to calculate the total and/or average accelerometer movement (in the X,Y,and Z axis) between consecutive GPS points?

Sorry if this is in-concise but this is my first question on Stackoverflow and I'm struggling to explain my problem.

Let me know if you have any questions, cheers.

Comment: Do you know if the accelerometer takes exactly the same number of measures to create the average it reports, each time it reports? For example, is it always reporting an average of 5 measures each second? How are you getting the Z movement - is it also from the GPS, or is the accelerometer also taking an X, Y, Z measurement?

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you're trying to find a way to remove the NA by summarizing the X, Y and Z via a mean or a sum. The easiest approach I can think of is using the "fill" function in tidyr to fill the NAs using the value above it. Since the timestamp ensures the readings are happening at the same time, this would work really well. I made a small example to illustrate this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x <- data.frame(X=rnorm(10),
                Y=rnorm(10),
                Z=rnorm(10),
                Distance=c(24, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                Speed=c(5.25, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.29, NA, NA, NA, NA))
#             X          Y          Z Distance Speed
# 1  -1.3361468 -0.1936848 -0.2837453       24  5.25
# 2  -1.0706103  0.7209007 -1.8242874       NA    NA
# 3  -0.8110023 -1.3079038 -0.8429418       NA    NA
# 4  -0.2890044 -0.3292910 -0.8169546       NA    NA
# 5  -2.4361706  0.4852265 -0.2097149       NA    NA
# 6  -0.5268403 -0.8552196 -1.3850287       12  2.29
# 7   0.4624232  0.4020024 -0.9949628       NA    NA
# 8   2.1616679  1.4438716 -0.2616311       NA    NA
# 9  -0.8322044 -0.3617747  0.7135186       NA    NA
# 10  0.3073546  0.4992849 -0.3553337       NA    NA

# Use the fill function to copy the above example

y <- x %>% fill(Speed, Distance)
#             X          Y          Z Distance Speed
# 1  -1.3361468 -0.1936848 -0.2837453       24  5.25
# 2  -1.0706103  0.7209007 -1.8242874       24  5.25
# 3  -0.8110023 -1.3079038 -0.8429418       24  5.25
# 4  -0.2890044 -0.3292910 -0.8169546       24  5.25
# 5  -2.4361706  0.4852265 -0.2097149       24  5.25
# 6  -0.5268403 -0.8552196 -1.3850287       12  2.29
# 7   0.4624232  0.4020024 -0.9949628       12  2.29
# 8   2.1616679  1.4438716 -0.2616311       12  2.29
# 9  -0.8322044 -0.3617747  0.7135186       12  2.29
# 10  0.3073546  0.4992849 -0.3553337       12  2.29

# After which, the group_by function can be used with any Speed and Distance to find the average/total X, Y and Z

z <- y %>% group_by(Speed, Distance) %>% summarize(mean(X), mean(Y), mean(Z)))
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
# # Groups:   Speed [2]
#   Speed Distance `mean(X)` `mean(Y)` `mean(Z)`
#   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1  2.29       12     0.314     0.226    -0.457
# 2  5.25       24    -1.19     -0.125    -0.796
```

Hope this helps!